# "Thought on" vs. "Thought about" vs. "Thought of"

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

I googled the exact phrase "He thought on" in quotes and get back mostly quotes from the Bible or old texts.

Does it sound antiquated to say, "He thought **on** his cat, how he would chase mice..." vs. "He thought **about** his cat, how he would chase mice..." vs. "He thought **of** his cat, how he would chase mice..."

Or to say, "He smiled when he thought **on** it." vs. "He smiled when he thought **about** it." vs. ""He smiled when he thought **of** it."

I want to use "thought on" but I'm not finding many modern examples. Just checking to see how it sounds to the community and if there are any real differences in meaning between the 3 options I've listed.

Thanks!

Comment: See; http://www.freecollocation.com/search?word=think

Comment: "Your thoughts on the subject is solicited."  Here, 'thought' is a noun. In the cruise ship, he thought about his family.  He thought of a new method. Oh, it was wrong; I didn't think of it early.

Comment: Yes, it does sound old-fashioned or literary to say _think on_ something when you mean _think about_ it. My late mother, a Yorkshirewoman, used to tell me to 'think on' (without an object) when she wanted me to consider the implications of something I'd done wrong.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/q/127687/17956

Answer (score 1):

To "**think of**" something is a brief thought, a recollection of that something.

- "Seeing him jumping about like that make me think **of** my cat."
- "I think **of** you whenever I pass that restaurant."

To "**think about**" something means spending significant time recalling memories and details about it, possibly finding new meanings or relationships within the thoughts.

- "When you have time, think **about** the offer.
- "I was thinking **about** what happened last week, and I was wondering … ."

To "**think on**" something, is more archaic, but from these AV biblical examples, it seems to mean that one should keep something in mind as a background thought while thinking about something else or making a not directly related decision.

- I thought **on** my ways, and turned my feet … — Psalms 119
- … was minded to put her away privily.  But while he thought **on** these things, …  — Matthew 1:19–20
- While Peter thought **on** the vision, … — Acts 10:19

Comment: thanks for that. I tend to like the archaic version in some cases.

Comment: If you are taking the feeling of the words into consideration, I agree that “think on” feels more poetical.